# Create folder without read only attribute in C#

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to create a folder from my app in 'c:\' folder(eg:c\), but this folder is always created with "read-Only" permission.

I have tried the below codes but still unable to change the attributes. Please help me.,

Method 1

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(temppath);
File.SetAttributes(temppath, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.SetAttributes(temppath, FileAttributes.Archive); */
```

Method 2

```
di.Attributes = di.Attributes | ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
File.SetAttributes(temppath, File.GetAttributes(temppath) & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Method 3

```
foreach (string fileName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(temppath))
{
    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);

    fileInfo.Attributes |= System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
    // or
    fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
}
```

all these methods are not working or just changing the attributes of file and not folder.

Comment: About method 3: FileInfo keeps information about the file. If you modify a FileInfo object, nothing happens on the disk. So method 3 will not have any effect on the filesystem. A FileInfo object does also require a Refreh() to get in sync with the filesystem.

Comment: About the other methods: there is no concept of a read-only directory on Windows. Setting that flag through Explorer only makes all the files inside the directory read-only, the directory itself does not support it. See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/prevent-changes-to-a-file-or-folder-read-only.

Answer (score 5):

To create a directory:

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

From MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you wish to explicitly set access controls:

```
DirectorySecurity securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();
securityRules.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\destination\NewDirectory", securityRules);
```